# TypeError: Related Field got invalid lookup: balance

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to access a decorate from model. When I try to access this balance variable to generate a link, receiving all the accounts I get this error. I want to find all the accounts that has a balance of 0, so completed account.

```
    accounts = BillingAccount.objects.filter(
        provider=current_user.provider
    ).filter(
        user__is_activated=True
    ).filter(
        account__balance=0
    )

@property
def balance(self):
    payment_sum = Payment.objects.filter(
            payment_package__id=self.id
        ).aggregate(
            Sum('amount')
        ).get('amount__sum', 0.00)
    if payment_sum is None:
        payment_sum = 0

    remaining = self.revised_out_of_pocket_bill - payment_sum
    return remaining
```

Answer (score 0):

balance is a property (computed in Python) but it has no counterpart in the database (no balance field) so you cannot filter on it (not with QuerySet filter method at least).

You can iterate on the queryset to do your own filtering (bad, can cause performance issues)
You can also denormalize the balance (create a new field in the model) to store the result of balance, then do some filtering as you did.

Another option would be to create an sql query to get balance computed by your database on the fly, then filter on it.

You can look at .extra documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra